# Disable new scroll bar look and feel Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Can you give me some tips about how to disable the new type of scroll bar in Ubuntu 11?
Thanks

Comment: This might be a better question for [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-disable-overlay-scrollbars-in.html) is the first Google hit for "ubuntu scroll bar".